# Is my user's SSL Certificate being intercepted?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I have a user who is getting a warning in Chrome:

[image: Photo of browser showing insecure connection: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID]

When looking at the security tab, the user's details look like this:

[image: Screenshot of security tab in client's chrome with an error saying that the cert authority is invalid]

On all of our machines though, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of security tab in chrome with no errors]

Now, I realize that this could just be that the user's machine doesn't trust the GoDaddy CA, but when I asked the user to send me the cert from our website and compared the modulus using OpenSSL, I received different results only for the client's cert.

[image: Console window showing that md5s of the two certs don't match]

Does this mean my user's connection to us is being intercepted or could there be something in the configuration along the way that is different? Or does the user simply not trust my certificate authority and therefore the whole cert is somehow different?

Comment: Try running your site through SSL Labs test page: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: If the user gets a different certificate then there is likely some interception going on. But it could also be a misconfiguration on your part in that you have multiple IP addresses (also something like IPv4 and IPv6) and have different configuration on these.

Comment: The user should click "View certificate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not totally correct. It is not SSL certificate may be intercepted. The SSL certificate of a website is a publicly available entity.

The SSL **connection** may be intercepted, especially when your client's certificate has different hash from your own, as you confirmed in your case.

Such interception is common in the large corporate IT environments. A special hardware would intercept and proxy all SSL connection attempts. In that case a client's browser would get a SSL certificate, generated on that hardware. However I don't think it is case there, because a browser would have a corporate CA root certificate installed, and would not mark the website certificate as an invalid.

The first screenshot mentions invalid certificate authority. So you should analyze the client's certificate to determine, what CA it was issued by.

To do so, run the following command:

```
openssl x509 -in cert-user.cer -text -noout
```

Analyze these fields:

- Issuer
- X509v3 extensions -> Authority Information Access

Comment: Thanks Sergey! I found out that the client actually sent me a legitimate cert but it was for a different website! Now I can see that she simply doesn't trust our cert authority.